# Executing Hadoop commands through shell script

Tags: shell, hadoop

I am trying to solve 2 issues:

1. I am trying to execute following command `/home/<username>/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh` but when I execute the script I get error as HostKey Verification failed.
2. Also trying to execute: `scp /path/to/sourcefile <ip-address> /path/to/destination` then scripts executes without any error but no file gets copied.

Issue is somewhat similar to these issue: [Executing hadoop commands in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044686/executing-hadoop-commands-in-browser)

Please help me. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: 1) What user are you running the script as and 2) What machine are you SCP-ing to? How do you know no file is copied? You have to separate the IP and the path with a colon, not a space

Comment: I will be running shell script through php shell_exec(). I running Ubuntu os. will tryout suggestion of colon after ipadress.

Comment: There is not enough information to really help you... How have you installed Hadoop? The Host key error means that an SSH key is not correct

Comment: Hadoop is installed properly. ssh is working properly as running start-all.sh separately doesn't give any such error.

Comment: Okay, then the PHP script is being ran by a user without an SSH key

Comment: Changed the ownership of  php script by 'sudo chmod <username> /var/www/filename.php` still error remains the same for host key verification. even scp command doesnot work even after adding colon after ipadress. scp command runs normally throughterminal

Comment: No, the permission is not what you need to change. You need to change the user that runs the Apache server process or give that user an SSH key

Comment: done with `sudo adduser tejas www-data`

Comment: I don't know how exactly, I just have a good idea that's what you need to do

Comment: done adding user to apache server. still getting error `starting namenode, logging to /home/tejas/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop--namenode-tejas.out 192.168.1.104: Host key verification failed`

Comment: So, did you generate an SSH for the user running the Apache server and add the key to all nodes in the cluster?

Comment: Yes generated ssh for user running apache.  Performed following methods. 1. added user to run apache server by `sudo adduser tejas www-data`. 2. generated ssh keygen and added it to host by `ssh-copy-id -i /home/tejas/.ssh/id_rsa.pub tejas@192.168.1.104`